# Module available for forcing users to re-enter their password to view/edit certain user account fields?

Tags: 7, users, security

My users have custom fields for their user account that can contain some sensitive information. To protect against privilege escalation vulnerabilities, I'd like to make these fields only readable and editable after users enters their password.

Is there a module available for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a module that can force a user to relogin when they got to a specific section (like admin)?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/is-there-a-module-that-can-force-a-user-to-relogin-when-they-got-to-a-specific-s)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question is focused on page-level security. I'm talking about field-level.

Comment: I agree with @Laxman13 - the answer for the mentioned question fits this use case almost exactly.  Use [Persistent Login](http://drupal.org/project/persistent_login) and forget the user session when they reach the profile page.

Comment: @Chapabu If you agree with Laxman13, you can flag the question to be closed. The number of closing votes, and flags for closing a question are considered, when closing a question. I personally don't think it's a duplicate as the topic is different; if the answer is the same, that doesn't automatically means the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Chapabu - "almost exactly" is apparently pretty subjective. I think field-level security vs. page level is far from "almost exactly" the same. I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I apologise..I've re-read the question and perhaps [Field Permissions](http://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) _may_ be of some use to you (not marking it as an answer as it may very well not suit)?  Perhaps you could temporarily elevate the user role and allow permission for a certain user role and then remove said role after editing is complete?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this/these fields appear on a certain page/form so you can use the securepages module to define the node/id or page path to assure that only logged in/authenticated users can access it.  If not, then the login page will display.
You could also use the loginlogout to return to the calling page upon successful login.

Answer (score 1):

**On the per-Form-level:**

If you just want certain forms to be submitted with a password, you may extend the form with a password field and use hook_form_validate

1. add a password field to the form
2. implement hook_form_validate: only accept the submit if the password matches the users password.